# C# return a string from an anonymous arrow function

Tags: c#, api, rest, async-await

Hey fellow stackoverflowers,

So I am working with fecthing data from a REST API and try to create a string object that performs the call operation called GetUserRequests(), i want it to return the data from the endpoint.

This is the code for it

```cs
private string GetUserRequests()
        {
            string comments = string.Empty;
            webrequest.Enqueue("https://coolrestapiendpoint.com/stuff", null, (code, response) =>
            {
                // Catch errors before anything funny happens
                if (response == null) { LogError($"[GetUserRequests] Failed to GET webrequest\nCode: {code}\nResponse:{response}"); return; }
                if (DEBUG) { Puts($"[GetUserRequests] Response:\n{response}\n"); }

                switch (code)
                {
                    case 200:
                            comments += $"stuff parsed from the endpoint";
                        break;
                    case 500:
                        break;
                    default:
                        LogError($"[GetUserRequests] Unexpected webrequest response\nCode: {code}\nResponse:{response}"); return;
                }

            }, this, RequestMethod.GET, Headers);
            return comments;
        }
```

This is the code for calling it:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(GetUserRequests());
```

It returns a blank line... not the REST API data
I guess it is because the ´comments´ object isn't populated until the function has already been processed.

How would I approach this appropriately?

Thankful for all tips

Comment: What is `webrequest`? But  I would say that you need to wait for it to finish processing before returning via `return comments;`

Comment: If you must use `webrequest.Enqueue`, then you will need to show us what that does and how those requests are actually processed.

Answer (score 0):

You return `comments` before data comes from server. So it's required to wait that.

Use that method for wait WebRequest

```
private async Task<(string response, string code)> MakeRequestAsync(string url)
{    
    var responseText = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();            
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            return (new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd(), response.StatusCode.ToString());            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    });

    return responseText;
}
```

Then you can rewrite your code as

```
private async Task<string> GetUserRequests()
        {
            var (code, response) = await MakeRequestAsync("https://coolrestapiendpoint.com/stuff");
            
            // Catch errors before anything funny happens
            if (response == null) { LogError($"[GetUserRequests] Failed to GET webrequest\nCode: {code}\nResponse:{response}"); return; }
            if (DEBUG) { Puts($"[GetUserRequests] Response:\n{response}\n"); }

            switch (code)
            {
                case 200:
                    return $"stuff parsed from the endpoint";
                case 500:
                    return string.Empty;
                default:
                    LogError($"[GetUserRequests] Unexpected webrequest response\nCode: {code}\nResponse:{response}");
                    return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

```
Console.WriteLine(await GetUserRequests());
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `return default` instead of `return null`?

Comment: `MakeRequestAsync` does not have any `await` statements in it, which will trigger a compiler warning telling you that it will run synchronously. You should probably use `ReadToEndAsync()` and `await` it.